# grep multiple strings from multiple files and stop processing other files when first match found

Tags: bash, grep

I have ca 270 .bz2 log files (25 day logs) and one text file with ca 1500 usernames. What I need to do is find who of theese users are logged in in last 25 days. So I need to grep usernames from list of files and stop grepping when username is found in first file (when first match found).

My code works, but if in first file match found I do not need to process other files, break and search for another username, if it is found i.e. in third file, break and search for another username:

```
for i in $(cat /tmp/usernames.txt); do for j in $(ls *.bz2); do 
bzgrep -o -m1 $i $j; done; done
```

Here, if in fist file match found it breaks (-m1 flag) and starts searching for the same username in second file, but I do not need that anymore.

Problem: I need to inspect users who are not logged in in last 25 days. So I can reduce their permissions in the application. If user is logged at least once in last 25 days, I do not reduce his permissions.

Question is: I need to find whom of theese usernames exist in my log files. If username is found in one of the files at least one time stop searching for this user and start searching for another user.

Example: if user1 is found in file1, print it and stop searching for this user any more in this or other files. If user2 is found in file8, print it one time and stop searching in file9, file10, file11 ... file250. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: please state what do you need. what is the question?

Comment: you do not need nested loops. you can `bzgrep` match a name to list of files like this: `for i in $(cat /tmp/usernames.txt); bzgrep -o -m1 $i $(ls *.bz2); done` or match list of names on a file `for i in $(ls *.bz2); do bzgrep -o -m1 -f  /tmp/usernames.txt $i; done`

Comment: Side note : [don't parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) ; `for j in *.bz2; do ...` is more robust.

Comment: @DudiBoy There is no need to `$(ls *.bz2)` here, just `*.bz2` will work just the same and properly handle spaces in the filenames, etc. It is the wrong answer anyway, as it will return the first match from each of the files, which was the OP's specific issue..

Comment: Using your existing code you could just check the returned state from grep. Assuming it is compatible with unix grep: `EXIT STATUS: Normally  the  exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.  However, if the -q or --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error.` so adding `if $? ; then break; fi` might help?
       occurred.`

Comment: @GemTaylor, thanks. That works for me:
`for i in $(cat /tmp/usernames.txt); do for j in *.bz2; do bzgrep -o -m1 $i $j; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then echo $j; break; fi; done; done` -- it breaks when first matched username found and start processing next username in next files.

Comment: @serfgei Glad it helped. If you are at all concerned about path or file names with spaces in, then **please** use `while read` instead of `for cat`. If you must, use `cat file|while read` for readability.

Comment: @sergei That would print on 2 lines. You could consider the grep options `-q` or `-H`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this to get the list of user names that appear in any of the bzipped files:

```
bzgrep -o -w -F -f /tmp/usernames.txt *.bz2 | sort -u
```

and then a diff of that output against usernames.txt to see who has/hasn't logged in? Wrap it in a loop if it turns out to be more efficient to check one .bz2 file at a time:

```
for file in *.bz2; do
    bzgrep -o -w -F -f /tmp/usernames.txt "$file"
done | sort -u
```

and you could remove found user names from each iteration if that improves performance too:

```
sort -u /tmp/usernames.txt > /tmp/names.txt
for file in *.bz2; do
    bzgrep -o -w -F -f /tmp/names.txt "$file" | sort -u > /tmp/found.txt &&
    comm -23 /tmp/names.txt /tmp/found.txt > /tmp/left.txt &&
    mv /tmp/left.txt /tmp/names.txt &&
    cat /tmp/found.txt
    [[ -s /tmp/names.txt ]] || break
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional:

```
if [ -n "$var" ]; then
     echo "Match!"
     break
fi
```

This structure means that the conditional is True only when $var is not empty. The loop will stop when the condition becomes True.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If disk space isn't a concern I would ask bzip2 to decompress all the archives to a single file and invoke `grep -m1` on that file for each username :

```
bzcat *.bz2 > merged
while IFS='' read -r username; do
  grep -om1 "$username" merged
done < /tmp/usernames.txt
rm merged
```